# Node.js Express API: How to handle multiple callbacks

Tags: node.js, api, express, callback, http-headers

I have an API endpoint, which executes a function, which in turn listens to some events via a web socket and then throws the response of it back via a callback to the api endpoint, so the endpoint can respond with this object to a http request.

Sometimes I get only one event, sometimes I get two events from the listener. When only the first event appears, I have no problems. Because the second event has priority, I am using `setTimeout` to wait for it, in case it still appears.

The problem ist, when the second event appears, my API endpoint responds with its object, but afterwards it crashes. I suppose it has something to do with the second callback and I don't know how to handle it. This is how the code is structured:

```
app.get('/api/myendpoint', function(req, res) {

    myVar_1 = req.query.myvar1;
    myVar_2 = req.query.myvar2;

    myFunction(myVar_1, myVar_2, function(data, error) {
        if (!error) res.json(data);
        else res.json({"error": String(error)});        
    });

});


function myFunction(myVar_1, myVar_2, callback){

    listenOnSocket.someEvent(myVar_1,
        function(error, event) {
            if (error) callback(null, error);
            else setTimeout(function() {callback(event, null);}, 6000);
        }
    );    

    listenOnSocket.someEvent(myVar_2,
        function(error, event) {
            if (!error) callback(event, null); 
            else callback(null, error);
        }
    );

};
```

This is what my errors look like:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

Comment: I noticed that `myFunction` takes two arguments, but is being called in the request handler with three and that and the body of `myFunction` calls callback which isn't defined in the function.

Comment: have updated the code @QuiltyKim

Comment: I think what's happening is the firstly the `1st` event occurs the you set a timeout to call the callback function after a time interval. Then the `2nd` event occurs and it executes the callback and sends the headers. Then when the timeout is completed and the callback due to first function is executed in which you're again sending the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why its Happening?**

1. `1st` event occurs at which you set a `timeout` for `6000` ms to call the callback function.
2. `2nd` event occurs before `6000` and the callback executes due to event `2`. Response is sent here.
3. `timeout` completes and the pending function passed to `setTimeout` executes the callback which would send the response again and its not possible to send headers to a response after its sent.

**Solution**

A basic solution would be to check a flag variable in the function passed to set timeout that whether the `2nd` event has occured or not.

```
function myFunction(myVar_1, myVar_2, callback){

    let executed = false;
    listenOnSocket.someEvent(myVar_1,
        function(error, event) {
            if(!executed){
            executed = true
            if (error) callback(null, error);
            else setTimeout(function() {
                       callback(event, null);
                    }, 6000);
        }
       }
    );    

    listenOnSocket.someEvent(myVar_2,
        function(error, event) {
            if(!executed){
            executed = true;
            if (!error) callback(event, null); 
            else callback(null, error);
        }
       }
    );

};
```

Comment: And maybe have a single flag and set it when any of your events are fired and check that before calling callback so it would not be called if once called. Basically you have to ensure its not called again after its called.

Comment: This error is arising due to execution of callback more than once. You have to avoid that.

Comment: I think comments are a good source of refrence to the future users. So its better not to delete those.

Comment: I don't understand why this works. Your first version has made more sense to me. In this case if the first event is being thrown first and event if setTimeout is stopping the callback, the second one can't be  executed cause `executed` is already True!?

Comment: The older one wasn't covering all the cases to stop callback from being called more than once.